# C write/read from multiple named pipes

Tags: c, bash, ipc, named-pipes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int data, pipe1, pipe2;
    pipe1 = open("pipe1",O_RDWR);
    pipe2 = open("pipe2",O_RDWR);
    read(STDIN_FILENO,&data,sizeof(data));
    write(pipe1,&data, sizeof(data));
    data+=1;
    write(pipe2,&data, sizeof(data));

    close(pipe1);
    close(pipe2);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this program . Lets call it prog1 that writes the stdin value to pipe1 and the stdin value +1 to pipe2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int data, pipe1;
    pipe1 = open("pipe1",O_RDWR);
    read(pipe1,&data,sizeof(data));
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,&data, sizeof(data));
    close(pipe1);
    return 0;
}
```

and this program lets call it prog2 that reads from pipe1 and writes to stdout.
I also have prog3 that is identical to prog2 except it opens pipe2.

How can I combine them in bash to run correctly.
I have tried prog1 & prog 2 & prog3 but it does not work

Comment: I see `prog1` reads from stdin, run it in foreground. `prog3 & prog 2 & prog1`

Comment: do you have any idea how i could connect them if prog 3 reads from stdin and writes to stdin and if prog1 writes data+1 to stdout and not to a pipe?

Comment: You connect one stdout of the program with others stdin using `|` pipe redirection. `prog1 | prog2`.

Comment: so ```prog3 & prog1 | prog2 ``` or ```prog1 | prog2 & prog3```

Comment: `&` runs the command in background. `|` connectes two programs together. `prog1 | prog2 & prog3` runs prog1 and prog2 in the background connected together (prog1 stdout is prog2 stdin) and runs prog3. `prog3 & prog1 | prog2` runs prog3 in the background and connected prog1 stdout with prog2 stdin.